# How do i explain the last line to a third party

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

There is something about this code that I find it hard to explain to a third party. When recursively calling our function, what's the logic behind subtracting 2 from n?

```
function is_even(n) {
    if (n<0) {
        return Math.abs(n) 
    }
    if (n=== 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (n === 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return is_even(num - 2);
    }
}

console.log(is_even(8));
```

Comment: It runs the function again with the new arg.

Comment: It generates an error because num does not exist, that's how I'd explain it anyway.

Comment: Also for the negative bit, I assume you meant to do -> `return is_even(Math.abs(n))`

Answer (score 2):

So the logic here is that you basically can tell something is odd or even by subtracting 2 from it until it is either 0 or 1.

You subtract 2 because if you subtracted anything more you might overshoot and end up with a negative number. By subtracting two you are always going to achieve either 1 or 0 regardless of what number you start with.

If you start at 9

```
is_even(9)
9 - 2 = 7 | is_even(7)
7 - 2 = 5 | is_even(5)
5 - 2 = 3 | is_even(3)
3 - 2 = 1  => 1 indicates it is odd and the function will return
```

Perhaps writing out some examples like the above would be a good way to explain to a third party.

Answer (score 1):

I think your is_even function needs some tweak to work as intended:

```
function is_even(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        n = Math.abs(n)

    } if (n === 0) {
        return true;

    } else if (n === 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return is_even(n - 2);
    }
}
```

the function only check two things, if it's 0 then return True, if it's 1 return False.

If you are anything that's greater than 0 or 1, such as 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...

The recursive nature of the else statement means: You can always subtract 2 enough times to any positive number so it becomes a 0 or 1.

This is the same logic as if you divide any number with 2, your remainder is always a 0 or 1, if it's 0 then the number is even, if it's 1 then the number is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You keep subtracting 2 until n is either 1 or 0. If it is 0, it is even, and if it is 1, it is odd. By subtracting by 2, you are pretty much just find the remainder of n / 2.

```
function is_even(n) {
    if(n<0){
        return Math.abs(n) 
    } 
    if (n=== 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (n === 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return is_even(n - 2);
    }
}


console.log(is_even(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the line should be:

```
return is_even(n - 2);
```

instead of

```
return is_even(num - 2);
```

Coming to the explanation:

Given a number n, the function keeps on subtracting 2 from the number until the remainder is either negative,0, or 1.
If the number is odd, then on subsequent subtraction of 2 it will return 1. If it's even then the remainder will be 0.
If the number is less than 2 then the remainder will be negative. The point of calling the function again is to keep on subtracting 2 in a recursive manner until the final value is either 0,1 or negative.

When a negative value is passed, it returns the absolute value instead of determining the odd or even.

- In the first iteration -> n = 8, function called again.
- In the next
  iteration -> n = 6 i.e (8-2), function called again.
- In the next
  iteration -> n = 4 i.e (6-2), function called again.
- In the next
  iteration -> n = 2 i.e (4-2), function called again.
- In the next
  iteration -> n = 0 i.e (2-2), function stops and it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

is_num is a recursive function, a function that calls itself during its execution.
Now when you write "return is_even(num - 2);" then you are sending an argument which is 2 units lesser than the original value, which is num.
after return is_even(num - 2);... is_even will be called again but the value of the parameter, n, will be lesser by 2 units.

The value of n will keep on reducing and Recursion will go on until something is returned and that returned value will be received at the line which called it in the first place.

for further information, you may refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/)